# How would I prove $10^x> 1$ for $x>0$ without using logarithms?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was asked this question and got completely stumped. The person who asked this has instructed me specifically not to use logarithms. I know there is a more sophisticated way to explain exponentiation using limits of sequences (which would work here), but unfortunately limits are outside the reach in this particular context. So I was wondering, is there a simple way to explain why $0<x<1$ can only be expressed as negative powers of $10$ (or any other number greater than $1$, for that matter) using only high-school algebra? I suppose the proof doesn't have to be entirely rigorous, as long as it's sufficiently convincing.

Comment: The exponential is strictly increasing and $10^0=1$.

Comment: I would use $10<10^{x+1}$.

Comment: How do you *define* $10^x$ for real $x$, without using the logarithm?

Comment: @MartinR or even limits!

Comment: Bernoulli's Inequality perhaps?

Comment: @MartinR I don't know, hence my question. I was simply wondering if there even *is* a simple way that circumvents limits and all the formalities so as to be accessible to someone whose understanding of mathematics is based on intuition rather than rigour

Comment: @MartinR and AakashM I agree with both of you on the ambiguity of the definition. But then I think high school student might treat real exponentiation superficially as some similar object as the rational exponentiation, which is less ambiguous in definition.

Comment: you may want to look at $10^{\frac n m}$, prove that $10^{\frac n m}>1$ (when $n,m$ are positive integers, assuming $10^x$ is defined starting with $10^{\frac n m}$). Use things like if $a,b$ are both positive and less than or equal to $1$ then $ab\le1$, so if $0<a\le1$ then $a^m\le1$ for every positive integer $m$.

Comment: @Mirko I like your idea. I think that might work. I'll certainly try it

Comment: Now if we are treating this subject in a less rigorous fashion, then we might need to accept some facts as granted, but these facts are reasonable enough for a high school student to understand.

For the sake of argument, suppose the opposite is true, i.e. there is a positive real number $x$ such that $10^x < 1$. Then by raising both sides to the power $1/x$ (note that "raising exponentiation does not change sign of any term", hence does not affect the inequality), we get $10 < 1^{1/x} $, "in which the right hand side is equal to one". This gives a contradiction.

Comment: @KenHung Exponentiation does not change the sign but it *can* reverse an inequality. Think about why your argument doesn't also prove that $10^x > 1$ for $x < 0.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $x$ is a positive rational number $p/q$ (where $p$ and $q$ have no common factors), then we can define $10^x$ as
$$
\left(\sqrt[q]{10}\right)^p=\underbrace{\sqrt[q]{10} \cdot \sqrt[q]{10} \cdot \sqrt[q]{10} \cdot \ldots \cdot \sqrt[q]{10}}_{\text{$p$ times}} \, .
$$
For any positive integer $q$, the $q$-th root of $10$ is greater than $1$. This means that $10^x$ is greater than $1$ because the product of $p$ numbers that are greater than $1$ is greater than $1$.

There are no hiccups caused when $x$ is *irrational*, because in that case $10^x$ is defined in such a way that it is strictly increasing.

Comment: can you explain the last statement

Comment: One way to define $10^x$ for irrational $x$ is to require that it be greater than $10^a$ for all rational $a$ smaller than $x$, while also being smaller than $10^b$ for all rational $b$ greater than $x$. That's enough to narrow down $10^x$ to a single value. Irrational exponents simply cause the 'holes' in the graph to be filled up, and $10^x$ is still strictly increasing.

Comment: Wow, this is a great explanation. Very simple and stresses intuition without getting bogged down in the details

Comment: @ChubbyChef: Thank you. I forgot to add that for negative exponents, $10^{-x}=\frac{1}{10^x}$, but of course that is not relevant here.

Comment: @Joe The issue initially arose because the person who had asked the question got confused about why the graph of $\log$ looks the way it does, so in a sense it is relevant.

Comment: P.S. someone seems to have downvoted both the question and two legitimate answers, including this one. I would love if they would care to elaborate.

Comment: @ChubbyChef: In that case, see my updated answer. I specified that $p/q$ has to be positive. If $p/q$ was negative, then the definition $$10^{p/q}=\underbrace{\sqrt[q]{10} \cdot \sqrt[q]{10} \cdot \sqrt[q]{10} \cdot \ldots \cdot \sqrt[q]{10}}_{\text{$p$ times}}$$wouldn't make any sense because you can't multiply numbers together a negative number of times.